# PHP's real SESSION object

Tags: php, reference, httpsession, superglobals, var-dump

**EDIT:** (UPDATED)

Maybe my question was not clear enough. Ok, lets put it this way:

```
$arr["a"] = 10; 
var_dump($arr);
$arr["b"] =& $arr["a"];
var_dump($arr);
```

the first var_dump returns:

```
array
  'a' => int 10
```

While the second one returns:

```
array
  'a' => &int 10
  'b' => &int 10
```

If I *unset($arr["a"])* it will return:

```
array
  'b' => int 10
```

The rule is, when 2 or more variables "points" to the same content var_dump will display the reference with an ampersand character (&).

In the case of $_SESSION, even with  **register_long_arrays = Off** $_SESSION still shows a reference. So it is obvious that other variable is also pointing to the same content.

In other words, if I unset($_SESSION) there is still other variable somewhere that can be linked to. In the above example, when I *unset($arr["a"])* I can still recover that content if I create a link, something like: **$arr["z"] =& $arr["b"]**.

So, my original question was, does anyone know WHICH is that other variable? It is very probable that such variable do not exists... but I was wondering why inside PHP shows that reference.

Thank you

---

(Original question:)

When you create a session in PHP, for example:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["name"] = "my name";
```

and dump the GLOBAL variables with:

```
var_dump($GLOBALS);
```

you will see something like:

```
  'HTTP_SESSION_VARS' => &
    array
      'name' => string 'my name' (length=7)
  '_SESSION' => &
    array
      'name' => string 'my name' (length=7)
  'HTTP_SERVER_VARS' => 
    array
      ...
```

As you can see, both variables $GLOBAL[HTTP_SESSION_VARS] and $_SESSION are
references to other object's content... Do anyone knows which is that object?

In theory, if I unset both variables, somehow It must be possible to access that
content... any clue?

Thank you!

Comment: I have been looking at the Zend's PHP source code and it is interesting that in main/php_variables.c all superglobals are initialized but SESSION, which has it own file in ext/session/session.c. So far I have no clue if its possible.

Answer (score 5):

[`$HTTP_SESSION_VARS`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) is the old, deprecated, name for `$_SESSION` -- you should not use that anymore.

Those `$HTTP_*_VARS` variables are not necessarily set : they will only be if the [`register_long_arrays`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-long-arrays) configuration directive is enabled -- and, with recent versions of PHP *(i.e. PHP 5.3)*, it has been deprecated.

For instance, on my server, which is running PHP 5.3.2, the portion of code that you gave :

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["name"] = "my name";
var_dump($GLOBALS);
```

Only outputs *(after a couple of refresh, which explains the presence of the `PHPSESSID` cookie)* :

```
array
  'GLOBALS' => 
    &array
  '_POST' => 
    array
      empty
  '_GET' => 
    array
      empty
  '_COOKIE' => 
    array
      'PHPSESSID' => string 'fnlujfapqg7kdk1ocve6ndb282' (length=26)
  '_FILES' => 
    array
      empty
  '_SESSION' => &
    array
      'name' => string 'my name' (length=7)
```

No trace of any `$HTTP_*_VARS` variable : the `register_long_arrays` configuration directive is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't HTTP_SESSION_VARS for backward compatibility?

Answer (score 0):

Well, in PHP 5 `$HTTP_SESSION_VARS` is kept for compatibility reasons only. You are strongly encouraged to use `$_SESSION` instead. From the PHP manual:

> $HTTP_SESSION_VARS contains the same initial information, but is not a superglobal.
>   (Note > that $HTTP_SESSION_VARS and $_SESSION  are different variables and that PHP handles 
>   them as such)

**EDIT**
You say you "already know that"!? What's your question then? `$_SESSION` is NOT an object, after all, it's an ARRAY, a superglobal variable. No methods, no members. You can access it's values like you would with any other array: `$_SESSION['key']`.

You could write your own Session class that wraps around PHP's session management. Use the [session_set_save_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) method to bypass the built in session management and implement your own logic.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

It's an array of data that is stored in the session file, which is an actual temporary file stored on the server. Like both of them point to, it's an array, there is no 'Session' object. Those values are filled in when you run `session_start` which basically loads the data from the file based on the PHPSESSID cookie for that user.

Comment: Ok, thank you. So where is that array? why var_dump is showing a reference instead of a "normal" array as the rest of the superglobals?

Comment: -1|Nonesense. It's not a "file" on the server. It's kept in memory during runtime and is written to a "file" only after execution (if one uses file-based session handling, that is).

Comment: @aefxx: All servers use file-based sessions. You can go to the /tmp directory and see all the session files yourself. PHPSESSID is just a reference to the file where the session data is stored for that unique identifier at the path /tmp/sess_PHPSESSID. I can go in and open up all the session files and see the data inside them, they're all in the form `x|x:x:x;` in the file. The data has to be stored somewhere in order to be fetched again by `session_start`...

Comment: Ever heard of session_set_save_handler method? It allows you to implement your own session logic. Actually, file-based session storage is the default setting but anyone with little knowledge would use something like a memcached server to store their user's data.

Comment: Any way you do it you're still storing data in a file somewhere, which you either read the contents from or get from the memcache when you call `session_start`

Comment: You don't store data in a file "somewhere" when the data is held in memory. Reconsider .. but then again .. it's tiresome .. never mind, though.

Comment: I think we are getting out of the main question... I added the EDIT section so its easier to understand (sorry if my English is not good).